# Where is my Run option in the Start menu?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a *Run* command box link in the Start menu. Today when I booted my PC, that run command was missing.

I tried running commands such as `%system root%`, `msconfig.msc` in Start menu, but no results. I have searched Start menu properties for a *Run* menu – nothing found. I opened Task Manager to find New task to get a Run window, but it wasn't focused when I pressed <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. A message box returned:

> This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator.

What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to undo a very recent change is almost always [restoring the system to a previous state](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/System-Restore-frequently-asked-questions).

If that's not an option (e.g., if there's no recent restore point), you should be able to undo these changes manually, as detailed below.

> I have a *Run* command box link in the Start menu. Today when I booted my PC, that run command was missing.

To undo this change, right-click the **Start** button, go to **Properies → Start Menu → Customize...** and make sure the option **Run command** is checked. Then, click **OK** twice.

> A message box returned:
>
> > This operation has been cancelled due to restrictions in effect on this computer. Please contact your system administrator.

The `NoRun` value in the `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` keys of the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hives determine whether you can or cannot access the Run dialog:

- If `NoRun` is set to `1` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, you cannot.
- If `NoRun` is set to `0` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, you can.
- If `NoRun` is missing in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, the corresponding setting in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` decides. The latter has no effect if the first is present.

To remove the restriction from any user account, do the following:

1. Log into an Administrator account.
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to open Windows Explorer.
3. Open the **System32** folder (usually `C:\Windows\System32`).
4. Search for `cmd.exe`, right-click it and click **Run as administrator**.
5. Execute the following command:

   ```
    reg add HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer /v NoRun /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
   ```
6. Then,

   - to remove the restriction only from the current user account, execute the following command:

     ```
       reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer /v NoRun /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
     ```
   - to remove the restriction from a different user account, find out its SID by executing the following command:

     ```
       wmic useraccount get name,sid
     ```

     Afterwards, execute

     ```
       reg add HKU\<SID>\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer /v NoRun /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
     ```

     where `<SID>` is the user account's SID.
   - to remove the restriction from all existing users accounts, execute the following commands:

     ```
       for /f "tokens=1,2" %a in ('wmic useraccount get name^,sid') do @if not %a==Name if not "%b"=="" reg add HKU\%b\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer /v NoRun /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f 2>nul
     ```
7. **Reboot your computer to make the changes take effect.**

If you can't perform any of the steps, try [disabling UAC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Turn-User-Account-Control-on-or-off) or [booting in safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/start-your-computer-in-safe-mode).
If the problem persists after following these steps, execute

```
reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer /v NoRun
reg query HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer /v NoRun
```

to check if the registry values are still set to `0`.

If they aren't, I recommend reading [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now).

Comment: The `reg add` command supports the `/f` flag, which eliminates the need to pipe "yes" into it.

Comment: error pops up access denied

Comment: @GoKUl: Are you logged in as Administrator? Try [disabling UAC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Turn-User-Account-Control-on-or-off) or booting in [safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/start-your-computer-in-safe-mode). Since the problem started recently, you could also try [system restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/System-Restore-frequently-asked-questions).

Comment: no use on first two suggestion and I am an administrator-I have tried to create a new admin user-but same problem in both users

Comment: anyway without any other way system restore worked

Comment: Excellent answer! This is the reason SE sites exist :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are the system administrator, enter group policy editor, and navigate to User Configuration > Administrative Templates >  Start Menu and Taskbar.  Right click on "Remove Run from Start Menu" and click edit. Select either "Not Configured" or "Disabled".

[image]

If you are not the system administrator, ask your administrator to do the steps above.

Comment: not worked it was already not configured

Comment: oh. Sorry i don't know of any other way :(

Answer (score 0):

- Go to the control panel, aet the display to "small icons" and select "Taskbar and Start Menu Properties".
- On the "Start Menu" tab, left-click the "Customize" radio button.
- In the "Customize Start Menu" dialog box, scroll down to "Rin Command" and check the box.
- Left-click the "OK" button in the "Customize Start Menu" dialog box.
- Left-click the "Apply" button in tke "Taskbar and Start Menu Properties" dialog, then "OK".
- You should then find the Run Command at the bottom of the right pane when you click the "Start" button.